# Should I punctuate abbreviations for Old English, Middle English etc. in academic writing?

Tags: style, academic-writing, punctuation

When using an abbreviation such as OFr (Old French) or ME (Middle English) in academic writing, what is the best way to stylise it? Masses of punctuation looks messy, but I am concerned my assignment will be more difficult to read without it.

For example:

> ... e.g.: “domynacyon”, from the OFr *dominacion*; first appearing in the late 14th C.
>  is “decreas [-eth]” as a verb, from the OFr *descroistre*; ...

or:

> ... e.g.: “domynacyon”, from the O.Fr. *dominacion*; first appearing in the late 14th C. 
> is “decreas [-eth]” as a verb, from the O.Fr. *descroistre*; ...

Comment: Welcome to Writers! You should definitely consult whatever style guide you're using. That'd probably be MLA or APA, although there are others.

Answer (score 2):

1. *Old English* is **OE** or **OEng**.
2. *Middle English* is **ME** or **MidE** or **MidEng**.
3. *Early Modern English* is **EModE** or **EModEng**.
4. *Modern English* is **ModE** or **ModEng**.

There's significant variation because one doesn't always need to make every possible distinction. So use whatever combination of these you need. My general principle is to use the shortest simplest abbreviations possible -- otherwise, why abbreviate?

Some possibilities, of many:

- *OE, ME, ModE*  (if it's mostly about Middle English with a few Modern references)
- *OE, MidE, ME*  (if it's mostly about Modern English with a few MidEng references)
- *OEngl, MidEngl, ModEngl* (if you're being paid by the letter)

As for stylization, this is a matter for the editor to decide.
Consult the stylesheet for the journal you're submitting to.